# NDSolve "Coupled differential equation"

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages

I am trying to solve the given coupled differential equation using `NDsolve`.

$$
\begin{array}{c}
n''(r)+\frac{n'(r) T'(r)}{T(r)}+\frac{n'(r)}{r}+\frac{n(r) T''(r)}{T(r)}-\frac{n(r) T'(r)^2}{T(r)^2}+\frac{n(r) T'(r)}{r T(r)}-n(r)+e^{-r^2}=0\\
T(r) n''(r)+2 n'(r) T'(r)+\frac{T(r) n'(r)}{r}+n(r) T''(r)+\frac{n(r) T'(r)}{r}-n(r)+e^{-r^2}=0
\end{array}
$$

```
eq1 = Div[Grad[n[r] , {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"], {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"] + Div[(n[r]/T[r])*Grad[T[r], {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"], {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"] - n[r] + Exp[-(r^2)] == 0 ; 

eq2 = Div[T[r]*Grad[n[r], {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"], {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"] + Div[n[r]*Grad[T[r] , {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"], {r, h, z}, "Cylindrical"] - n[r] + Exp[-(r^2)] == 0 ;

initialConditions = {n'[50] == 0, n'[0] == 0, T'[50] == 0, T'[0] == 0};

solution = NDSolve[{eq1, eq2, initialConditions}, {n, T}, {r, 0, 50}];

Plot[Evaluate[{n[r], T[r]} /. %], {r, 0, 50}, PlotLegends -> {"n[r]", "T[r]"}]
```

**Mathematica returns an error -  NDSolve::bvdae: Differential-algebraic equations must be given as initial value problems**

I have two questions regarding it,
Q1: Can we solve such equations accurately with `NDSolve`?
Q2: How do I get initial values for the two quantities, `n` and `T`?

Comment: In V13.3.0, I get two messages, and the other one, which is printed first, seems more important. Did you not get that one?

Comment: If you get the other message, begin to address it by evaluating `Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {n''[r], T''[r]}]`. It suggests there's an error in your ODEs. And if no error, then the ODEs are inconsistent and there's no solution at all. (The first error is the source of the second in my trial, which is why you should address the first error first.)

Comment: @Shalu Rani:  (1)  Would behove you to search site for "differential algebraic equations" using search window above and read some of the threads, (2) Since cannot find explicit solutions for higher derivatives, may solve as IVP, (3) The DEs have $r$ and $T(r)$ in denominators so problematic at $r=0$, (4) Even if I set up as IVP with initial $r\neq 0$ again run into inconsistencies: Try solving for initial $T''[r_0]$ and $n''[r_0$] and cancelations of $T''[r_0]$ or $n''[r_0]$ occur likely causing the` NDSolve::ivres` message.

Comment: @Shalu Rani:  Took the liberty to edit your post with the DEs in Latex.

Comment: @josh The DEs are inconsistent (the coefficients of $n''$ and $T''$ are proportional). You cannot fix that by adjusting ICs. The only hope is that the OP made a mistake in coding the DEs.

Comment: @Michael E2:  would you mind explaining, briefly, what you mean by "proportional?"  Do you mean the $T(r)n''(r)$ and $n(r)T''(r)$ terms?  If that's so then would changing these terms to say $r n''(r)$ and $n(r)T''(r)$ eliminate the problem?

Comment: @josh the coefficients of n’’ and T’’ in each DE form a pair. The pair in the 2nd DE it’ is T(r) times the pair in the 1st DE.  Like a x + b y = 1, k a x + k b y = 3 : The coefficients of x and y are proportional.

Comment: @josh Doesn't changing only one term, $T(r)n''(r)$ to $r\,n''(r)$, change the problem to something completely different?

Comment: @MichaelE2 The ODEs are not inconsistent, but the question does have too many boundary conditions.

Comment: @bbgodfrey As a system in two variables $A_1 \, n''(r) + B_1 \, T''(r) + C_1 = 0, A_2 \, n''(r) + B_2 \, T''(r) + C_2 = 0$, it is inconsistent. It's linear algebra, not ODEs, that I'm talking about. `Solve[]` will tell you so, too.

Comment: Unless they're redundant, of course. I thought I checked that though....Don't remember now.

Answer (score 3):

The pair of ODEs can be solved as follows.  Begin by eliminating the second-derivative terms from `eq2`.

```
eq3 = Simplify[T[r] Subtract @@ eq1 - Subtract @@ eq2] == 0

(* E^-r^2 (-1 + T[r] - E^r^2 n'[r] T'[r]) + n[r] (1 - T[r] - T'[r]^2/T[r]) == 0 *)
```

Because `n[r]` and its derivatives enter the ODEs at most linearly, they can be eliminated to obtain an ODE for `T[r]` as follows.

```
Solve[{eq3, D[eq3, r], D[eq3, r, r]}, {n'''[r], n''[r], n'[r]}] // 
    Simplify // Flatten;
Simplify[{eq2, D[eq2, r]} /. %];
eqs = Equal @@@ (Simplify@Solve[%, {T'''[r], n[r]}] // Flatten)

(* {T’’’[r] == (-4 r^2 (-1 + r^2) T[r]^5 + r T[r]^4 (12 r (-1 + r^2) 
    + (-7 + 8 r^2) T’[r] + r (5 - 4 r^2) T’’[r]) + 
    r T’[r]^2 ((-2 + 4 r^2) T’[r] + 4 r T’[r]^2 + r (-1 + 2 T’’[r])) + 
    T[r] ((2 + 4 r^2 - 4 r^4) T’[r]^2 - 8 r^3 T’[r]^3 + 2 r^2 T’[r]^4 - 
    r^2 (-1 + T’’[r]) T’’[r] + T’[r] (r - 2 r^3 - (r + 2 r^3) T’’[r])) + 
    T[r]^3 (2 (1 - 5 r^2 + 2 r^4) T’[r]^2 + 
    r T’[r] (15 - 18 r^2 + (-1 + 10 r^2) T’’[r]) + 
    r^2 (-12 (-1 + r^2) + (-9 + 8 r^2) T’’[r] - T’’[r]^2)) + 
    T[r]^2 ((2 r - 8 r^3) T’[r]^3 + T’[r]^2 (-4 + 7 r^2 - 2 r^2 T’’[r]) + 
    r T’[r] (-9 + 12 r^2 + (2 - 8 r^2) T’’[r]) + 
    r^2 (4 (-1 + r^2) + (3 - 4 r^2) T’’[r] + 
    2 T’’[r]^2)))/(r^2 (-1 + T[r])^2 T[r] (2 r T[r] - T’[r])), 
    n[r] == (E^-r^2 T[r] (r + r T[r]^2 + (1 - 2 r^2) T’[r] - 
    2 r T’[r]^2 + T[r] ((-1 + 2 r^2) T’[r] + r (-2 + T’’[r])) - 
    r T’’[r]))/(r T[r]^3 - r T’[r]^2 + T[r]^2 (-T’[r] + r (-2 + T’’[r])) + 
    T[r] (r + T’[r] - r T’[r]^2 - r T’’[r]))} *)
```

An important point is that it is a third-order system, so only three boundary conditions can be specified, not four as in the question.  In the absence of suitable boundary conditions, I offer the following solution with made-up initial conditions:

```
NDSolveValue[{eqs, T[1] == 2, T'[1] == 0, T''[1] == 0}, {T[r], n[r]}, {r, 1, 3}];
Plot[%, {r, 1, 3}, AxesLabel -> {r, "T,n"}, LabelStyle -> {12, Bold, Black}]
```

[image]

**Solution without `eqs`**

An even simpler approach, at least for the sample solution, is

```
NDSolveValue[{eq2, eq3, T[1] == 2, T'[1] == 0, n'[1] == -.7}, 
    {T[r], n[r]}, {r, 1, 3}];
```

which produces an answer very close to that plotted above.

Comment: @bbjodfrey:  Thanks for that interesting approach.  I back-substituted your solutions into the original system over the range {r,1,3} and the error was on the order of $10^{-6}$, and no doubt improving with greater working precision.

Comment: @josh, after submitting my answer above, a ran the calculation above over a wider range and found that the simpler approach, "solution without eqs" was more robust.  By the way, solving the boundary-value problem given in the question (of course, without one boundary condition) probably is possible, although challenging due to the strong nonlinearity of the ODEs.

Answer (score 0):

This seems an overdetermined system.You get

```
     res1 = Solve[eq1 , T''[r] ][[1]]
```

$$\left\{T''(r)\to \frac{e^{-r^2} \left(-e^{r^2} r T(r)^2 n''(r)-e^{r^2} r T(r) n'(r) T'(r)-e^{r^2} T(r)^2 n'(r)-e^{r^2} n(r) T(r) T'(r)+e^{r^2} r n(r) T'(r)^2+e^{r^2} r n(r) T(r)^2-r T(r)^2\right)}{r n(r) T(r)}\right\}$$

But there is no solution for n''

```
    Simplify[eq2 /. res1 ] // FullSimplify
```

$$n'(r) T'(r)+n(r) \left(\frac{T'(r)^2}{T(r)}+T(r)-1\right)=e^{-r^2} (T(r)-1)$$

Using this equation as a replacement for n', there remains an undefined n in the equation for T''.  Conclusion: There is an error in the algebraic ansatz.